# Membership Renewal Reminder Issue

Tags: wordpress, scheduled-reminders

We have been having issues trying to add a scheduled email reminder for members that have a membership expiring in two weeks. Every time we try - CiviCRM stalls and the logo simply spins.

Only error I can find is

```
send @ jquery.min.js?r=kX8Gx:4
/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2FscheduleReminders&action=add&snippet=json:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
```

also the warning:

```
send @ jquery.min.js?r=kX8Gx:4
/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2FscheduleReminders&action=add&snippet=json:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
```

I was not able to duplicate in the demo - any idea what is happening?

Latest wordpress and CiviCRM

Answer (score 3):

Turns out Wordfence was blocking the param for the following reason:

blocked by firewall for XSS: Cross Site Scripting in POST body: 
User in city left https://domain.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2FscheduleReminders&reset=1 and was blocked by firewall for XSS: Cross Site Scripting in POST body: html_message=%3Cp%3E%26nbsp%3B%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%0A%3Cp%3E%3Cmeta%20charset%3D%22utf-8%22%20%2F%3E%3C%2Fp%3E%0A%0A%3Cp… at https://domain.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2FscheduleReminders&action=add&sni…